# How can I add two items to a list copmprehension at once

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a simple for loop like this:

```
for i in range(3):
    if i == 1:
        for x in [0, 2]:
            free_spots.append([x, i])
    else:
        free_spots.append([1, i])
```

which outputs this list
`[[1, 0], [0, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2]]`

I planned to convert this to a list compehension like so but ran into a problem:

`[[x, i] for x in [0, 2] if i == 1 else [1, i] for i in range(3)]`

This causes an error, which I've tried fixing it like this:

`[[[x, i] for x in [0, 2]] if i == 1 else [1, i] for i in range(3)]`

and while that this now runs it also creates this:
`[[1, 0], [[0, 1], [2, 1]], [1, 2]]`
and I don't want items 2 and 3 to be in a list together. Is it possible to do something like this?:
`[[0,i],[2,i] if i == 1 else [1, i] for i in range(3)]`

Comment: There isn't an *elegant* way to do this. I recommend instead writing a generator function and then collecting the results in a list.

Comment: The logic you've shown seems pretty weird out of context.  Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: Please keep in mind that a primary design goal of the Python language is readability.

Comment: If you have to go through this much trouble trying to create a list comprehension, it's not worth it. The loops are fine.

Comment: @0x5453 Interesting, but the full context of the project is quite long and i'm not sure if I'll get a better answer for the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps.

```
free_spots = [[1, i] for i in range(3)]
free_spots[1:2] = [[x, 1] for x in [0, 2]]
```

The slice assignment is equivalent to the nested loop in the `for` loops.

However, this doesn't generalize well if you have multiple exceptions in the loop.

Comment: I ended up going with this, its quite short and is readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to do it in one line, how about this?

```py
free_spots = [val for sublist in [([[x, i] for x in [0,2]] if i == 1 else [[1, i]]) for i in range(3)] for val in sublist]
```

```py
# This effectively creates a list of lists containing the values you want
main_list = [([[x, i] for x in [0,2]] if i == 1 else [[1, i]]) for i in range(3)]
# And then flattens it
free_spots = [val for sublist in main_list for val in sublist]
```

But the others are right. This is not a good idea unless you have a good reason. I can barely understand my own code now that I've written it which is not python zen.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out in the comments, it is not elegant to create such a list comprehension statement. Therefore, as suggested in [Karl's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68367076/how-can-i-add-two-items-to-a-list-copmprehension-at-once#comment120827466_68367076), a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) is a preferred solution.

To use a generator, your code will look somehow like this:

```py
# Create a generator function
def generate_data():
    for i in range(3):
        if i == 1:
            for x in [0, 2]:
                yield [x, i]
        else:
            yield [1, i]

# Use it
print(list(generate_data()))
```